# Will Salesforce DX work with a custom profile?

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli

Does anyone know if I HAVE to use the standard user profile if I want to assign the Salesforce DX permission set?(I know I can also use sys admin)Or will it still work if I give them a custom profile? Sorry, it was a little unclear in the Salesforce documentation for DX Implementation.

**EDIT**

For background the developers currently have admin access in our Production which isn't best practice. I just want to make sure they will still be able to create scratch orgs if I assign them a read only profile(for instance) and give them the Salesforce DX permission set.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SFSE! I suspect this may be an [X-Y Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). You might want to **[edit]** your question to include whatever specific problem you're having that's prompting this question. In the general case, you should be able to use any profile you like, not just the system administrator profile, but without more information, I'm not sure we can help you resolve your specific problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use any standard or custom profile as long as it is a Salesforce License type. The Permission Set should grant the appropriate level of access as [outlined in the documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_setup_add_users.htm#sfdx_setup_add_users). We personally have a "Limited Developer" profile that we use for developers, and we all have access to DX via this permission set.

Comment: Link to docs doesn't work, here's the current one: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_setup_add_users.htm#sfdx_setup_add_users and

Comment: @ChristianSzandorKnapp Thanks! Those pesky links are always changing on me.